# Python) How to copy a row and paste it to all rows in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I extract a specific row and paste it to all rows in another dataframe? 
For example, when I have two dataframes as below:

```py
df1={'category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)

df2={'value 1': [1, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 4, 8, 7],
    'value 2': [4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 9, 3, 4, 2]}
df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)

df1
#  category
#0        A
#1        B
#2        C
#3        D
#4        E
#5        F
#6        G
#7        H
#8        I

df2
#   value 1  value 2
#0        1        4
#1        1        2
#2        2        8
```

I'd like to copy the forth row to all rows in df1

```py
df3
#  category   value 1  value 2
#0        A        1        2
#1        B        1        2
#2        C        1        2
#3        D        1        2
#4        E        1        2
#5        F        1        2
#6        G        1        2
#7        H        1        2
#8        I        1        2
```

---

Thanks to Axe319, I change the code as in the comment.
But I check that there was unexpected result.

```py
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.apply(lambda _: df2.iloc[1], axis=1)], axis=1)

df3
#  category  value 1  value 2
#0        A      1.0      2.0
#1        B      1.0      2.0
#2        C      1.0      2.0
#3        D      NaN      NaN
#4        E      NaN      NaN
#5        F      NaN      NaN
#6        G      NaN      NaN
#7        H      NaN      NaN
#8        I      NaN      NaN
```

I guess that it only fills according to the number of rows in df2, but I cannot understand this situation.

Comment: Something like `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.apply(lambda _: df2.iloc[3], axis=1)], axis=1)`?

Comment: @Axe319 Sorry, but can you check the revised question? There was a problem...

Comment: You can use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to fill the `NaN` values. `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.apply(lambda _: df2.iloc[3], axis=1)], axis=1).ffill()`. Or simply `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.iloc[[3]]], axis=1).bfill().ffill()`.